# ImportError using Flask and GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

I'd like the app engine to associate index.html with the root URL and main.app with /stats. Here's my app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html

- url: /stats.*
  script: main.app  

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*)
```

If the URL is /stats, I'd like to print a short message. Here's the code in main.py:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/stats')
def stats():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

When I try to access /stats, the GCP log says `ImportError: No module named main`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you entered in a conflict between the `/stats` handler and the `/(.*)` handler. As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) for `static_files`:

> If a static file path matches a path to a script used in a dynamic handler, the script will not be available to the dynamic handler.

So, either remove the `/(.*)` handler, or, as you intent to serve static files with it, I recommend using a handler like the one described in the documentation:

```
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|whateverextension))$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|whateverextension)$
```

Also, don't forget to add the Flask library to your `app.yaml` file:

```
libraries:
- name: flask
  version: 0.12
```

Comment: No problem at all @MatthewScarpino :) Glad to see that it worked for you!